# Using LTI (which uses oauth2) how to initiate a query to canvas LMS API?

Tags: servlets, oauth-2.0, lti

Canvas is a Learning Management System which uses LTI (Learning Tools Interoperability) to connect to third party web sites and authenticate.

We are writing a tool. We have a working server that shares a secret with canvas, and can therefore receive messages. When a user clicks on the link, the user id is passed to the server. We can execute our code, and then when we return we want to insert a grade into the system. Canvas has a REST API for such things:

```
https://canvas.instructure.com/doc/api/index.html
```

For example, to list courses we would use:

```
canvas.instructure.com/api/v1/courses
```

However, this will fail because the user must embed an oauth token in the query to authenticate. How does LTI pass the authorization back to Canvas so we can write the grade?

Answer (score 1):

What you're looking for is not actually specific to LTI, it's the standard OAuth2 processflow. You need to start by making the Tool POST to the Platform's token-retrieval endpoint, usually something like `oauth/token` (especially if the Platform uses Laravel-Passport).

I'm actually building the other side of this equation at the moment, wiring up a Platform LTI integration, and right in the middle of adding 'Assignments and Grades' support. After the OIDC handshake and Deep Link request including permission scopes for things like the Assignments and Grades service, IMS Global's [Test Suite](https://www.imsglobal.org/lti-certification-suite) reaches out to the Platform API to obtain an OAuth2 token to be included in subsequent Assignment and Grade API calls, and that's where your authentication would come from.

Actually, their Test Suite seems to be failing to include a 'client_id' in the initial OAuth2 paylaod, despite the fact that that or a 'client_secret' is a required field when the grant_type is 'client_credentials' as it is. This seems wrong, but I'm not certain if it's a bug in their utility, or of there's some LTI-specific implementation here. At the moment, my workaround is to tell their utility that the OAuth endpoint includes a GET parameter with a client_id of my choosing.

Here is what they're sending me, what I presume is similar to what your Tool would have to supply (not sure if you're limited to this grant_type, I suspect any OAuth2 format will suffice):

```
grant_type: client_credentials
client_assertion_type: urn:ietf:params:oauth:client-assertion-type:jwt-bearer
scope: https://purl.imsglobal.org/spec/lti-ags/scope/lineitem
client_assertion: eyJraWQiOiJpbXN0ZXN0ZXJfNSIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCIsImFsZyI6IlJTMjU2In0.eyAic3ViIiA6ICJMZW8gSWQiLCAiaXNzIiA6ICJMZW8gSWQiLCAiYXVkIiA6ICJMZW8gYXVkIiwgImlhdCIgOiAxNjA4MDYwMDUwLCAiZXhwIiA6IDE2MDgwNjA0MTAsICJqdGkiIDogImM1MDRmOWVjOGU5OTQyYjdhYzU1NTViZjhhMDE1ZWU1IiAgfQ.JLOATz1vkBj5nn0mBu4-K-CCUeGwLaW6vXieuH0JAZjLBQb606Ba6Mw31jcHryRVBrIv1-1Tzgva8EITVwsd4_z-EUdGrT6qZlBc3bidECPalD8OwT9she0mtUgaMgBetMI3ZSpXV5PCMESMGY9hOlVfWH8ygE0AciVINE6deTf8QlHmu8a1POAzQaxFr7Lpv5bGzXq-DJ9nKFHl3FahWENLr_9PqFjtmapE3ZfruLemR7qq03qiWW8XP82qfX300B-4-SdFpxg_JgwuGGqfBVYavqQT4UcBqv6OQXDyFpAJjUx6hZ6WOEv3ArVn4M4nCGVH-2qXJmm7OUvoGNdEng
```

That `client_assertion` value is a JWT that you can plug into https://jwt.io to see the content of. The Platform would be expected to reach back to the Tool's JWKS endpoint (again, not an LTI-specific thing) to obtain the public key with which to validate the JWK. The Tool may actually supply an array of public keys, so the `kid` in the JWK signature would be used to select the appropriate one.

This security step is akin to getting an email from your bank, and rather than click a potentially-spam link therein, you call your bank directly to make sure the email is on the level. Of course, without the `client_id`, it'd be like not knowing which bank to call, so as I said, still working through that one. (If you're interested in how to convert PEMs to JWKS, I have a [gist](https://gist.github.com/kmuenkel/37ead59ff01f56ee881744c11360b00c) with helper functions for that.)

At any rate, once the Platform validates and unpacks that token, it's free to hand back a JWT of its own to be used by the Tool as an authorization token. I'm not entirely clear yet on what the token claims would be yet, especially considering the scope claims would have already been communicated to the Tool during the preceding Deep Link call, but hopefully that insight helps get you at least part of the way there.

Answer (score 0):

Based on your description I'm going to guess that your tool is using an LTI 1.1 integration (where you exchange a consumer key and secret with Canvas).

In order to passback a grade from an LTI 1.1 tool you need to use the special [LIS Grade Passback Service](https://canvas.instructure.com/doc/api/file.assignment_tools.html#outcomes_service).

Essentially during an LTI 1.1 launch there is are two fields that are present during the launch `lis_outcome_service_url` and `lis_result_sourcedid`

Then when you are ready to submit the grade back to the platform you create a [replaceResult POX message](http://www.imsglobal.org/specs/ltiv1p1/implementation-guide#toc-26) and POST it back to the url specified in the `lis_outcome_service_url` field.

If/when you update your application to LTI 1.3 Advantage, this flow is replaced by a simpler one where there is a [line_item service endpoint](https://www.imsglobal.org/spec/lti-ags/v2p0/) that you can read and write data from.

It should be noted that neither of these APIs use the proprietary Canvas APIs that are listed above, but use lms platform agnostic LTI flows and will work in any of the IMS certified platforms.